# App works on device via direct install but doesn't via ipa

Tags: ios, compilation, ipa

I've been surfing the net and have found no answer to this situation I have (though I find it surprising because I can't believe I'm the first one to come over this). Maybe I don't know the correct keywords for finding it...

My problem is I build an iOS app with XCode 4.2 and test it running directly in an iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1 and everything runs as it is supposed to.
However, if I build an .ipa and install it in that same device (where I have previously uninstalled the former installation of the app), it install perfectly and almost all the app works fine... but for one place that is not working properly.

I don't enter in details of what is exactly happening because it is something that has happened before in other apps with other devices (i.e. ipad 1, iphone 4...) (once I found out that compilation and execution directly to a Device was letting an uninitialized rect being added to something, while in .ipa it crashed (I think it was a SIG_ABRT but don't know exactly).

Is this situation documented anywhere? What cases compile in one way and others don't?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please paste the crash log here so we can get a sense of what is going on.

Comment: It might have to do with your compiler settings.  Usually an ipa will have compiler optimizations set to `-Os` (fastest, smallest).  This could potentially cause a race condition.

Comment: dtuckernet there is no crash log because nothing is crashing here, there's just some drawing (using 2D drawing functions) that is not working the way it should.

Sam I'll try something with the flags and see what happens.

Comment: Sam, I've compiled the ipa without optimizations and everything works perfectly! Thanks for your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to select "None" for Optimization Level in the section "Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 - Code generation" of Build Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Philip J. Fry's answer: "Try to select "None" for Optimization Level in the section "Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 - Code generation" of Build Settings."

It still is the proper answer today with "Apple LLVM compiler 8.1 - Code generation"

be careful changing it both target and project...

Comment: Thanks for keeping track of the issue with new versions :)